# How can I make this SQL more Efficient

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, relational-database

I have written this piece of SQL, I know there are ways to make it run faster, with the right practices.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ACCOUNTNUM,
    FIRSTNAME AS NAME, 
    LASTNAME AS SURNAME, 
    (PHONE + ' ' + CELLULARPHONE) AS PHONENUM, 
    EMAIL,
    (SELECT TOP 1 CREATEDDATE 
     FROM RBOTRANSACTIONTABLE 
     WHERE CUSTACCOUNT = ACCOUNTNUM 
     ORDER BY CREATEDDATE DESC) AS LASTVISIT,  -- LAST VISIT, 
    (SELECT COUNT(TRANSACTIONID) 
     FROM RBOTRANSACTIONTABLE 
     WHERE CUSTACCOUNT = ACCOUNTNUM) AS TOTALVISITS, -- TOTAL VISITS, 
    (SELECT SUM(PAYMENTAMOUNT) 
     FROM RBOTRANSACTIONTABLE 
     WHERE CUSTACCOUNT = ACCOUNTNUM) AS TOTALSALES, -- TOTAL SALES,  
    (SELECT SUM(DISCAMOUNT) 
     FROM RBOTRANSACTIONTABLE 
     WHERE CUSTACCOUNT = ACCOUNTNUM) AS DISCOUNT
FROM 
    CUSTOMER 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    RBOTRANSACTIONTABLE ON CUSTACCOUNT = ACCOUNTNUM
```

I know if I am using some sort of Joins, I don't have necessarily have to keep saying `FROM RBOTRANSACTIONTABLE` every time (the code after `Email` column). The code above works great for my requirement, but I know there are missing gaps in my knowledge, I just don't know *what*.

I am looking for in-depth answers as to why the above solution is not recommended, and why your solution is.

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database. Assuming that you are using SQL Server: See [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: You used DISTINCT to cover up your logic error. There is **NO** reason to join Customer and Transaction when you do the equivalent as subqueries. And you used 4 separate subqueries to **the same table** for your calculations, each of which is a simple aggregate. That should have been a clue that you could calculate all 4 values with a single pass through the transaction table - as Tim demonstrates. lastly - [top 1 x order by x desc] is the same as max(). The latter is far more readable, more understandable, and less prone to error.

Answer (score 3):

You may rewrite your query as a join to a subquery which finds aggregates:

```
SELECT
    c.ACCOUNTNUM,
    c.FIRSTNAME AS NAME,
    c.LASTNAME AS SURNAME,
    (c.PHONE + ' ' + c.CELLULARPHONE) AS PHONENUM,
    c.EMAIL,
    a.LASTVISIT,
    COALESCE(a.TOTALVISITS, 0) AS TOTALVISITS,
    COALESCE(a.TOTALSALES, 0) AS TOTALSALES,
    COALESCE(a.DISCOUNT, 0) AS DISCOUNT
FROM CUSTOMER c
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        CUSTACCOUNT,
        MAX(CREATEDDATE) AS LASTVISIT,
        COUNT(TRANSACTIONID) AS TOTALVISITS,
        SUM(PAYMENTAMOUNT) AS TOTALSALES,
        SUM(DISCAMOUNT) AS DISCOUNT
    FROM RBOTRANSACTIONTABLE
    GROUP BY CUSTACCOUNT
) a
    ON c.ACCOUNTNUM = a.CUSTACCOUNT;
```

You should *always* use proper aliases when referring to columns in the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Tim's is definitely a good way to rewrite the query.  But you can also make your version more efficient by getting rid of the `count(distinct)` and outer join:

```
SELECT ACCOUNTNUM,
       FIRSTNAME AS NAME, 
       LASTNAME AS SURNAME, 
       (PHONE + ' ' + CELLULARPHONE) AS PHONENUM, 
       EMAIL,
       (SELECT TOP 1 CREATEDDATE FROM RBOTRANSACTIONTABLE WHERE CUSTACCOUNT = ACCOUNTNUM ORDER BY CREATEDDATE DESC) AS LASTVISIT,  -- LAST VISIT, 
       (SELECT COUNT(TRANSACTIONID) FROM RBOTRANSACTIONTABLE WHERE CUSTACCOUNT = ACCOUNTNUM) AS TOTALVISITS, -- TOTAL VISITS, 
       (SELECT SUM(PAYMENTAMOUNT) FROM RBOTRANSACTIONTABLE WHERE CUSTACCOUNT = ACCOUNTNUM) AS TOTALSALES, -- TOTAL SALES,  
       (SELECT SUM(DISCAMOUNT) FROM RBOTRANSACTIONTABLE WHERE CUSTACCOUNT = ACCOUNTNUM) AS DISCOUNT
FROM CUSTOMER c;
```

With the right indexes, this could even have better performance than the `group by`/`join` version.